# file_put_contents():: failed to open stream: Permission denied, resize CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, upload, resize

**Controller**: Here i want to resize the image that is stored on some another server, but here I'm getting permission denied error. How can I solve this issue?.
Thanks in advance.

```
public function img_r()
    {   

        $image = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/omjb1vMWKKK3dvcZKGjHbx_zp-cwOgP7zT4blbLLS1BsIpq7JC8dgRYCXG73Ghwst8QXrSodAEl54vCwljdky06-";
        $data = file_get_contents($image);

        /*store image in server*/
        $new  = FCPATH."assets\img";

        /*Write the contents back to a new file*/
        file_put_contents($new,$data);
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $new;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']    = 700;
        $config['height']   = 450;
        $config['new_image'] = FCPATH."assets\uploads".$image;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its permission issue .Plz give write permission to the directory where you want to store file.

Comment: full access permission is given, and I'm using windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
```

Also can put the value to execute 0755

Comment: what is $name @Thoppil

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `php-cgi.exe` don't have permission to write that folder Also might be check whether as 'user' you have rights to change folder permission or not.

You can refer this :
https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/ 
https://forums.iis.net/t/1167645.aspx